# Custom system tray icon "balloon tooltips" for Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, system-tray, balloon

I know that in the .NET framework there are a handful of alternative third-party controls for normal system tray icon "balloon tips", that allow you to change the colors and add some styling to the balloon.

I was wondering if there is something similar for Qt, which allows for better customization of the look, style, and feel of the balloon tooltips from a system tray icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a quick glance at the "Qt Style Sheets" examples in QtAssistant. It provides strong and many ways to alter widgets looks and feel... Maybe you'll find something interesting there !

Otherwise, you could have a look at QSystemTrayIcon & QBalloonTip. Maybe by reimplementing those classes...

Hope this help a bit !